# How does one add different local bind addresses in PuTTY?

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, ssh-tunnel

I have the Windows 10 included SSH client installed. I use the following command (but different IPs and ports) in PowerShell to set up an SSH connection to a remote server.

```
ssh -l username 1.2.3.4 `
   -L 127.100.100.1:8080:192.168.1.1:8080 `
   -L 127.100.100.2:8080:192.168.1.2:8080
```

I need to occasionally ssh through a SOCKS5 proxy.  How do I configure PuTTY tunneling so it does the same thing as the command line `ssh`?

The target port number is hard-coded in the client software.
I have not been able to locate how to set the local bind address for each forwarded port.

As an option, is there a way to proxy from the Windows command line SSH directly? I've tried to use `netcat`/`ncat`/`nc` for Windows, but the local anti-virus (I don't control it) keeps quarantining them.

Answer (score 0):

When configuring the forwarding in PuTTY, in the small *Source port* box your actually put both hostname and port with syntax:

```
host:port
```